# Why laravel validation not work correct when validate for empty string?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.7

**Brief:**

I have validate request value for empty string.

**Code:**

```
if(isset($request->name)) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => [
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if (mb_strlen(preg_replace('/\s/', '', $value)) == 0) {
                    $fail($attribute.' is can't be empty.');
                }
            }
        ]
    ]);
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->save(); 
}
```

Also tired with cutom rule.

**Rule code:**

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $result = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $value);
    return mb_strlen($result) == 0 ? false : true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    return "Attribute value can't be empty string.";
}
```

**Rule testing code:**

```
if(isset($request->name)) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => [
            new IsEmptyString
        ]
    ]);
    $user->name= $request->name;
    $user->save(); 
}
```

**Question:**

Where I've errors? Why laravel not sending validation error message when I check request value for empty string?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course the validations doesn't work for empty string. validation is not even call for an empty string, because you have put it inside an `if` condition.

Comment: It is well understood @Tharaka Dilshan , but what if I check each field separately with conditions only? How to do validation then? An empty string is also not recorded in the database in my case, but I cannot notify the user that he entered an empty field.

Comment: Other types of validation inside the condition work in my case, only when the empty string does not work.

Comment: Yes that's because you have put the validate function inside an `if(isset($request->name))`. don't you understand that if the `name` is empty, the validate function is not even called.

Comment: I understand you @Tharaka Dilshan. But how then can I tell the user that he entered an empty string?

Comment: do it in the validation. example `'name' => 'required'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, you must change your condition to:

```
if(array_key_exists('name', $request->all())) {

}
```

When you check `isset($request->name)` and this condition result return **false** and the validation code does not even run and for the fact that the conditions returned false.

Generally, your working code looks like this:

```
if(array_key_exists('name', $request->all())) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => [
            'required',
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                if (mb_strlen(preg_replace('/\s/', '', $value)) == 0) {
                    $fail($attribute." is can't be empty.");
                }
            }
        ]
    ]);

    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->save();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Felix Cruz, your code work inside condition

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `if()` condition. and then add the `required` rule to the validation.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => ['required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if (mb_strlen(preg_replace('/\s/', '', $value)) == 0) {
                $fail($attribute.' is can't be empty.');
            }
        }
    ]
]);
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->save();
```